# Is is possible to create symlink inside another symlink?

Tags: windows-8.1, symbolic-link, windows-server-2012

I have the below folder structure:

```
My Windows Machine
   |-- E:
       | -- myphotos   <== link to ==> \\192.168.0.10\\myphotos
       |                                                   |--photo2011
                                                           |--photo2012
```

Now I tried to do the below:

```
MKLINK /D E:\myphotos\p2012 E:\myphotos\photo2012
```

but windows CMD seems not able to access network drive.

Is there a way to do it from "my machine"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of but also of note is that if ANY of the 3 files gets deleted (intentional or accidental) both symlinks are trash as one links to the other.